# Read and execute lines with spaces from file in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm facing a problem in a bash shell script when I try to read some lines from a file and execute them one by one. The problem occurs when the line has an argument with spaces. Code:

```
while read i
do
   $i
done < /usr/bin/tasks
```

tasks file:

```
mkdir Hello\ World
mkdir "Test Directory"
```

Both of the above instructions work perfectly when executed directly from the terminal, creating only two directories called "Hello World" and "Test Directory" respectively, but the same doesn't happen when the instructions are read and executed from the script, meaning that four directories are created.

Having said that, I would like to keep my code as simple as possible and, if possible, I'd prefer not to use the cat command. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's your real goal here? If you're trying to add logging, error handling, or the like, then there are better ways to do it.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as possible? You are re-implementing the `.` (or `source`, as `bash` allows you to spell it) command:

```
. /usr/bin/tasks
```

or

```
source /usr/bin/tasks
```

---

To execute one line at a time, use `eval`.

```
while IFS= read -r i; do
    eval "$i"
done
```

This assumes that each line of the file contains one or more *complete* commands that can be executed individually.

Comment: Code edited. Anyway, any idea how to solve the issue with the spaces?

Comment: There shouldn't be an issue with the spaces. If the commands in `/usr/bin/tasks` work when typed that way on the command line, they should work if you simply source the file.

Comment: Simply sourcing the file works very well, but I really need to use the while loop to execute one line at a time from the file tasks (sorry if I didn't mention that before). Is that possible?

Comment: @user3437174, why? Some programs *can't* be executed one line at a time -- anything with flow control constructs that span lines, for instance.

Comment: @user3437174 ...also, if you have redirection operators, or syntactical quotes, those won't work the way you're currently doing it either. In those cases, you **must** use eval -- which you certainly can use one line at a time, as chepner demonstrates here.